# Mapping Microsoft struct in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, struct, ef-code-first

I want to map a Microsoft struct in EF Code First. My first solution has been to create a model class of that struct, and a method to convert the model to the Microsoft Class (the same approach as ViewModels). My question is: is there any way to avoid creating model classes and methods to convert model class to struct?

Now

```
namespace Microsoft.Kinect
{
    public struct Joint
    {
        public static bool operator !=(Joint joint1, Joint joint2);
        public static bool operator ==(Joint joint1, Joint joint2);

        public JointType JointType { get; internal set; }
        public SkeletonPoint Position { get; set; }
        public JointTrackingState TrackingState { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Joint joint);
        public override bool Equals(object obj);
        public override int GetHashCode();
    }
}

namespace Models
{
    public class JointModel
    {
        public JointType JointType { get; set; }
        public SkeletonPointModel Position { get; set; }

        public JointModel(JointType jointType, SkeletonPointModel position)
        {
            JointType = jointType;
            Position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something to say Map struct Joint to table... I prefer to use only one class, and don´t have to switch between model class and struct.